# ERROR - Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I am trying to insert data into an MS Access DB through a VB.net Windows Forms App

when executing this code

```
  Dim con As New OleDbConnection(CS)
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Ports ([PortNumber] , [DistributionBoardLocation] , [DistributionBoardSubLocation] , [PortLocation] , [PortSubLocation] , [PortDevice] , [POE]) VALUES('" & nudPortNumber.Value & "', '" & txtDBLocation.Text & "', '" & txtDBSubLocation.Text & "' , '" & txtPortLocation.Text & "' , '" & txtPortSubLocation.Text & "' , '" & txtPortDevice.Text & "' , '" & chPOE.Checked & "'", con)


            con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()

                MsgBox("New Port Has Been Created")
```

i get this error message -

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

Please Help

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: We'll need the actual SQL string. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 0):

You insert every value as text which probably is not the case. Adjust that, for example for the port number:

```
.. VALUES (" & nudPortNumber.Value & ", ..
```